# Running Windows Update inside Windowx XP Mode

Tags: windows-update, windows-xp-mode

I am working on a Win 7 Ultimate machine, and was using XP for some development tasks (for compatibility checks). Everything worked like a charm on the XP, including updates.

Two days ago I had to switch computer (mainly a new motherboard/cpu), and I had just stuck my old HD inside the newer case. Win 7 worked like a charm - installed all the new drivers, identified everything automatically, no sweat. The trouble started when I tried running my old XP mode - it won't launch, complaining about the cpu change. I figured it's not a big deal, and I deleted the VM, and re-ran XP mode. It told me it can't find it, and offered to create a new one, just what I wanted.
I had finished setting up the new XP mode VM, and it seems to work just fine. Got it to use the host network adapter, so I can surf from "inside". But I can't get Windows Update to run. Whenever I click on the "Custom" button on the WU site, after a short while, I get the `[Error number: 0x80072EFD]` page.

I tried several solutions from around the web for it (clearing some cache and restarting the wuauserv, even a microsoft fix-it run), but still nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took several tries, but I got it to work -
I had no luck with removing and reinstalling the XP Mode. Got the same problem when trying to run Windows Update. Surfing the web worked just fine from the VM.
I then updated manually to IE8, and after a reboot of the VM, couldn't even surf at all. I fiddled around the IE Connection Settings, unticked the "Automatically Detect Settings" in the Lan Settings dialog, and had internet again, *while being able to use Windows Update!*
It might even have worked on the original IE6 - worth a shot if anyone is stuck with a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

At this point in time IE8 appears to be a *must* -- I had the same issue, and WU started working after I updated IE6 to IE8.

Prior to that, I updated the update agent and installer (WindowsUpdateAgent30-x86-7.6.7600.256-257 & WindowsXP-KB942288-v3-x86) and manually set my LAN connection.

Answer (score 0):

This error just means no connection possible to the Windows Update site.

This Microsoft article lists some more points to verify:
[You may encounter temporary connection-related errors when you use Windows Update or Microsoft Update to install updates](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/836941)

Another possibly useful article discusses limitations that Windows Update places on XP Mode:
[Windows XP Mode Internals – Part 2 (Application Publishing Magic)](http://www.withinwindows.com/2009/04/28/windows-xp-mode-internals-part-2-application-publishing-magic/)
(use with caution)

Comment: Thanks for offering your help, but I have already tried the fixes offered by MS over there.
And I don't understand the 2nd link. My previous XP Mode VM updated itself without any problem or special hack...

Comment: @Noam Gal: I would guess that something went wrong with deleting the XP VM, maybe because of a Microsoft bug. Perhaps you should uninstall XP Mode and restart from scratch. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zxue/archive/2010/01/27/uninstall-windows-xp-mode-and-deleting-vhd-files.aspx and also http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee431673%28WS.10%29.aspx.